# Getting error 'RCTView' when updating API level 28

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

`react-native: 0.57.8`
`react: 16.6.3`
`react-navigation v2`

I am trying to update the API level to submit the app (they are requiring the latest targetSdkVersion). I have added the following changes

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"  // from '27.0.3'
minSdkVersion = 19
compileSdkVersion = 28 // from '27'
targetSdkVersion = 28  // from '26'
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0" . // from '27.1.1'
```

dependency left it without change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

And updated the `gradle version` from `4.6` to `4.10.1`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Also created a folder by the name `debug` and added a `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Now the app builds and run fine, I can even view the first page and login page, but once the main page (tabs) of react-navigation loads it shows this error

```
Error while updating property 'transform' of a view managed by: RCTView
null
Cannot set 'scaleX' to Float.NaN
```

[image]

Can someone please help, thanx

Comment: have you fixed it yet? I got this issue too